# AJAX problem with IE9 (and other IE versions)

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, internet-explorer-9, activexobject

I am having problem with XMLHttpRequest object in IE9, IE8 and probably IE7 too, although have not tested in IE7. It works without problem in FF4, Opera 11.01 and Chrome 10.
First I would like to explain for what I use this code. I have a HTML select tag, with option Time defined in it. Then when the user clicks on a button, it dynamically updates select with time values from database. Now here is the code for creating XMLHttpRequest object:

```
var xmlhttp = false;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        try {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {
                xmlhttp = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see, if the creation of XMLHttpRequest object fails, it tries to create ActiveXObject.

Now the code for sending request and getting response:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById(time).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "getTime.php?d=" + str, true);
      xmlhttp.send();
```

I send the parameters to getTime.php, and the response is written back to select tag with id=time. Now in IE9 and IE8 it does not want to populate the select tag with time from DB.

EDIT:
I will add code from getTime.php:

```
<?php
$username="something";
$password="";
$database="somethingDB";

$date = $_GET["d"];
$timestamp = strtotime($date);
$nextDay= $timestamp + (1 * 24 * 60 * 60);// 7 days; 24 hours; 60 mins; 60secs
$date2 =  date('Y/n/j', $nextDay);


$link = mysql_connect('localhost', $username, $password);
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db($database, $link);
$query="SELECT TIME(Date) FROM someTable WHERE Date >= '" .$date. "' AND Date < '" .$date2. "'";
$result=mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
    die('Could not query:' . mysql_error());
}
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    echo "<option>" .$row[0]."</option>";
}

mysql_free_result($result);

mysql_close($link);
?>
```

EDIT2:
Ok, I have added wrap, according to [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/276228). Now I will also post the code select tag, which is now wrapped:

```
<div id="wrap">
        <select id="Time1" name="Time1" disabled="disabled">
            <?php if (empty($_GET['Time1'])) { echo "<option>Ura</option>"; } else { echo '<option>' . $_GET['Time1'] . '<option>'; } ?>
        </select>
    </div>
```

The code in getTime.php is now also changed, I will post only the section which is changed:

```
echo '<select id="Time1" name="Time1">';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    echo "<option>" .$row[0]."</option>";
}
echo '</select>';
```

As you can see, I only added echo '....' before and after while statment. Guess what happens now. In FF, Opera and Chrome it works without a problem, but in IE9, it now gets the values, but it does not put them in the drop down menu, it just prints them as actual text. Also the drop down menu has dissapeard when the values are printed as text. Seems like it does not want to include select tag. I don't get it, why is that only with IE?

Comment: Have you verified that getTime.php? is passing a value that is not undefined?

Comment: Yeah I have forgot to write, that it indeed does probably return something, but it is just blank. So where before user clicked send, under select tag it was Time, now there is just empty select tag. But it could not be something wrong with getTime.php, because then it would not work in FF, Opera and Chrome aswell.

Comment: Yes, but there are elements such as "innerHTML" which are not supported by all version's / scenarios of IE.

Comment: I have added getTime.php in first post. If innerHTML isn't supported, then what can I use?

Comment: Thanks, I dont think that is your problem if you said it is working in Firefox.  When you get element by id "time" is that a variable? If not it should be in quotes.  Is element with id containted in "time" a text box?

Comment: Yes it is a variable, if you mean this time inside parantheses: document.getElementById(time).innerHTML. No element is select tag. Meanwhile I have searched some more and found this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/276228, is it possible that this bug is still present in IE9?

Comment: If it works fine without innerHTML then I would say that is indeed your problem my friend :) Like I mean, if you just change it to alert("Response"); does it fire no problems?

Comment: I have updated my first post. Could you please read after the EDIT2. Thanks!

Comment: I **ALWAYS** suggest using a 3rd party JS plugin for AJAX (like jQuery). This improves cross-browser compatibility, and also reduces code by a factor of at least 10 times. (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: It sounds like this has nothing to do with XHR at all, and everything to do with using innerHtml on a SELECT object. You might want to adjust your question and build the simplest possible repro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the right solution [here](http://www.phphaven.com/article.php?id=6). I already had the select tag in the div box, the missing code was this part:

```
document.getElementById('box').style.display = 'block';
```

Apparently without this, the IE will just print it as actual text, instead of populating the select object.

Answer (score 0):

IE has problem with 'select' tag. You cannot just replace the 'option' tags inside only, you have to replace the opening and closing 'select' tags also.